# Django vs Node(Express) vs Flask for RESTful API with high security and real-time

Tags: javascript, python

I have a few questions regarding some popular web frameworks. I can find pros and cons about all the frameworks, but which fits best regarding theese criteria:

The website needs to be as secure as possible. It will need a lot of real-time feautures, an own mobile app (native or hybrid, with notifications) and the application will also run a lot of background processes.

Django has some nice security features included, but suits bad for mobile development. The solution is then probably making a completely RESTful API tougheter with Angular and Ionic, but doesn't you loose most of Django's built in security solutions? Will it then be just as safe using a Node framework like Express, and manually escape user input, and manually prevent database injection? Will a good user authentication system then be equal as much work?

In addition, will it be painful to mix synchronous and asynchronous programing using Django channels to implement websockets and real-time features. I don't have any experience using Django channels, but I really likes the simplicity of Socket IO together with Express. Even if it can be challenging to program asynchronous in a Node environment, will it be just as hard using Django channels at the end? And since Django is a full framework, will you after a while have to rewrite a lot of the inbuilt classes and functions? Is it still easier than using Flask with Flask SocketIo? Will it be a good idea to use Python for background jobs beside the Node environment?

I know there already exists enough framework vs framework questions, but i would appreciate any advice and experiences.

Comment: Some thoughts about the comparison python and node web frameworks https://hinty.io/ivictbor/flask-vs-node/

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and use the **socketio** in node or flask it is much more **adviceable** than using the **socketio** libary in Django.